# database constraint with a condition from another table

Tags: database, constraints

I want to make a database constraint that's based on another table condition. I am using postgres database.

TableA

```
id     value    
7890    none
2345    none
1394    change
2412    none
5432    change
```

TableB

```
rank    name      table-a-id    category
29      David         7890         A
13      May           2345         A
10      Charles       1394         B  
01      Rose          2412         A
62      Robby         5432         B
```

I need to make a database constraint when Table A value = change, then Table B must have category = B.

My attempt so far:

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD CHECK (SELECT 1 FROM TableA a, TableB b where a.value = "change" and b.category = "B")
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to do this with a trigger. A constraint is only able to look it's own row. With a trigger, you can look at other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, at least as of the latest version of Postgres, to use a query inside a check constraint.  But, we can try handling this via a trigger as a workaround:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_table_a()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b
    WHERE b.category = 'B' AND b.table-a-id = NEW.id)
THEN Raise Exception 'TableA id % does not have B category', NEW.id;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER check_me
BEFORE UPDATE ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_table_a();
```

Comment: You can use a function in a check constraint as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you're feeing magnanimous, you may edit my answer (or post another one) with this option.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am a bit confused on where does the joining of table A, and what's the NEW table from?

Comment: @Matt-pow My trigger does not use a join.  And [see here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html) to read about `NEW`.